# RowLimit not working in SharePoint Online CAML query

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, caml

For some reason RowLimit does not work in SharePoint Online. I was wondering if RowLimit is supported feature. If so, what's wrong in below query?

```
<View><Query>
<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='SiteStatus'/><Value Type='Text'>Completed</Value></Eq></Where>
<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='FALSE'/></OrderBy></Query>
<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/></ViewFields>
<RowLimit>2</RowLimit>
</View>
```

Query Mode: PowerShell PnP

Answer (score 2):

If executed on a library with more than 5000 the row limit does not work.

```
$Query.ViewXml = "@
       <View Scope='RecursiveAll'>  
            <Query> 
               <Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><Value Type='Text'>A2.xlsx</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy> 
            </Query> 
             <ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields> 
            <RowLimit>4999</RowLimit> 
      </View>"
```

Even though the query only has 1 result.
It still ends with the threshold error (same as in get-pnplistitem)

Answer (score 1):

If the list/library has more than 5000 elements, you could create an index for the column that you're using in your "where" conditions. That'll solve your problem.

For your example, you should create an index for "SiteStatus" column.
To better performance results is a good idea to create an index for "ID" column also, because it's been used in "OrderBy" conditions.

```
<View><Query>
<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='SiteStatus'/><Value Type='Text'>Completed</Value></Eq></Where>
<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='FALSE'/></OrderBy></Query>
<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/></ViewFields>
<RowLimit>2</RowLimit>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested with the CAML Query in CSOM PowerShell, the RowLimit option is working as expected:

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

#Set parameter values
$SiteURL="https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/"
$ListName="listname"

#Get Credentials to connect
$Cred= Get-Credential

#Setup the context
$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$Ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)

#Get the List
$List = $Ctx.Web.lists.GetByTitle($ListName)

#Define the CAML Query
$Query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$Query.ViewXml = "@
       <View>  
            <Query> 
               <Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='SiteStatus' /><Value Type='Text'>Completed</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy> 
            </Query> 
             <ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields> 
            <RowLimit>2</RowLimit> 
      </View>"

#Get All List Items matching the query
$ListItems = $List.GetItems($Query)
$Ctx.Load($ListItems)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

Write-host "Total Number of Items:"$ListItems.count

#Loop through each List Item
ForEach($Item in $ListItems)
{
    Write-host $Item.id
    Write-host $Item["Title"]
}
```

This is the test list data:

[image]

When executing the PowerShell, it will return the last two items which SiteStatus equals Completed:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Jerry. I wonder if PnP has any limitation, because that's what I'm using. I will go through your code now. In case it still doesn't work, I will post my code in the question above.

Comment: I'm testing with SharePoint CSOM PowerShell, will test with PnP PowerShell and give you updates.

Comment: Indeed PnP PowerShell not accept RowLimit parameter in CAML, I can reproduce.
And there is same issue have posted in GitHub:
https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/issues/879
Instead, please limit row count like this in PnP PowerShell:
Get-PnPListItem -List 'yourlist' -Query 'the CAML'  -PageSize 4 | select -first 2